# Direction relay polar characteristic

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, transformer, relay

I need help on how to draw polar characteristics for a directional relay. The circuit I have is:

[image]

For this we have that zone 1 is 80% of the closest line and zone 2 is 120% of the closest line length. VT ratio is 220000:66 and the CT ratio is 500:5. The line impedance is (0.06 + j0.24) Ω/km.

Looking at B32 I have that on the secondary side Z<sub>r1</sub> = 0.072 + j0.288 and Z<sub>r2</sub> = 0.108 + j0.432. The trip time for zone 1 is 0.2 s and zone 2 is 0.6 s.

I need to indicate setting points and line angles. I don't quite understand what setting points are either. I would love an explanation on how to do the polar characteristics.

Comment: Those reach point impedances are points on the circle of each Mho distance (I am assuming they are Mho) at the elements characteristic angle.  Once you plot on complex plane, draw the circle that goes through that point and through the origin.

Comment: Yes @relayman357 they are Mho, I have got up to that point but what is the setting points? Is that just the Zr1 and Zr2 impedance lines?

Comment: Yes, the settings are specified as secondary ohm magnitude at angle. e.g. zr1 would be 0.297 @ 76 deg